# How to determine if a string was only edited once in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, edit

I am trying to determine if a string was only edited once. When I enter the following strings (see code below), the output is incorrect. The program should print that the string was edited only once and this is not what I can see on my screen. Can anyone help me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "cat";
        String str2 = "ca";
        char[] arr1 = str1.toCharArray();
        char[] arr2 = str2.toCharArray();
        int n = str1.length();
        int m = str2.length();
        if (stringWasEdited(str1, str2, arr1, arr2, m, n)) {
            System.out.print("The string was edited only once.");
        } else {
            System.out.print("The string was not edited or was edited more than once.");
        }
    }

    private static boolean stringWasEdited(String str1, String str2, char[] arr1, char[] arr2, int m, int n) {
        int count = 0;
        if (Math.abs(m - n) > 1) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
                count++;
            }
            if (m > n || n > m) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > 1 || count == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-strings-are-at-edit-distance-one/

Comment: For more general tasks look at [Levenshtein Distance](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/similarity/LevenshteinDistance.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is you're only looping throughn the length of one string, when you should be looping through from the i < m && i < n. This is a good reference:

```
static boolean isEditDistanceOne(String s1,
                                 String s2)
{
    // Find lengths of given strings
    int m = s1.length(), n = s2.length();
 
    // If difference between lengths is
    // more than 1, then strings can't
    // be at one distance
    if (Math.abs(m - n) > 1)
        return false;
 
    int count = 0; // Count of edits
 
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < m && j < n)
    {
        // If current characters don't match
        if (s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(j))
        {
            if (count == 1)
                return false;
 
            // If length of one string is
            // more, then only possible edit
            // is to remove a character
            if (m > n)
                i++;
            else if (m< n)
                j++;
            else // Iflengths of both strings
                // is same
            {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
             
            // Increment count of edits
            count++;
        }
 
        else // If current characters match
        {
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
 
    // If last character is extra
    // in any string
    if (i < m || j < n)
        count++;
 
    return count == 1;
}
```

Link for reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-strings-are-at-edit-distance-one/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to check for exactly one edit, rejecting strings that have zero or more.

Given two strings (`s1, s2`), where `s1` is longer than or equal in length to `s2` (reverse the parameters if this is not the case) we can check for a single edit using the following:

1. Filter out cases where the difference in length is greater than 1.
2. Consume the first sequence of equal characters.
3. If you've reached the end of `s2` then check that `s1` is longer. If it's not then `s1 == s2` and the condition is not met.
4. Consume the second sequence of equal characters. If `s1` is longer (by one) then we need to use an offset of 1 when accessing characters in `s2`.
5. If you've reached the end of `s1` then the condition is met.

The above translated into Java ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/czS92Y)):

```
static boolean hasOneEdit(String s1, String s2)
{
    // ensure s1 is longer than or equal to s2
    if(s1.length() < s2.length()) return hasOneEdit(s2, s1);
    
    // difference in length cannot be more than one
    if(s1.length() - s2.length() > 1) return false;

    int pos = 0;
    
    // consume 1st sequence of equal characters
    for(; pos < s2.length() && s1.charAt(pos) == s2.charAt(pos); pos++); 
    
    // if we reached the end of s2, s1 has to be longer (by 1)
    if(pos == s2.length()) return pos < s1.length();

    // offset into s2 depends on whether strings are equal in length
    int off = s1.length() - s2.length();
            
    // consume 2nd sequence of equal characters
    for(pos += 1; pos < s1.length() && s1.charAt(pos) == s2.charAt(pos-off); pos++);
    
    // did we reach the end of s1?
    return pos == s1.length();
}
```

And a small test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s1 = "dirigible";
    for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++)
    {
        String s2 = s1.substring(0, i) + s1.substring(i+1);
        test(s1, s2, true);
        for(int j=0; j<s2.length(); j++)
        {
            String s3 = s2.substring(0, j) + "x" + s2.substring(j+1);
            test(s1, s3, false);
        }               
    }
    for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++)
    {
        String s2 = s1.substring(0, i) + "x" + s1.substring(i+1);
        test(s1, s2, true);
        for(int j=0; j<s2.length(); j++)
        {               
            String s3 = s2.substring(0, j) + s2.substring(j+1);
            test(s1, s3, j == i);
        }
    }
}

static void test(String s1, String s2, boolean check)
{
    boolean result = hasOneEdit(s1, s2);
    System.out.println((result == check ? "PASS" : "FAIL") + ": " + s1 + " " + s2 + " = " + check);
}
```

Output:

```
PASS: dirigible irigible = true
PASS: dirigible xrigible = false
PASS: dirigible ixigible = false
PASS: dirigible irxgible = false
PASS: dirigible irixible = false
<Truncated>
PASS: dirigible dirgiblx = false
PASS: dirigible diriiblx = false
PASS: dirigible dirigblx = false
PASS: dirigible dirigilx = false
PASS: dirigible dirigibx = false
PASS: dirigible dirigibl = true
```